# How to track PersistentVolume usage with prometheus for non gp2 storage class?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am running a kubenetes cluster in an ubuntu node. I have created a persistent volume (storage class: openebs-hostpath) and corresponding claim. I want to track how much of the claim is being used by the pod. How do I do this?

When I used gp2 storage class on aws, I was able to get the usage using the metric `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes`. However, I don't see this metric on the ubuntu prometheus.